# Связи сущностей в Symfony

Tags: doctrine2, entity, relation, symfony3

Упрощенный пример. Имеем сущности User и Post. Каждый пользователь может проголосовать за пост. НО при этом пользователь имеет возможность оставить голос анонимно.

Идея: создать таблицу с полями user_id, post_id, anonym(bool).

Пишу сущности по примеру из документации http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional:

```
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_voice")
     */
    private $voices;

    // ...
}

class Post
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="voices")
     */
    private $users;

    // ...
}
```

Успешно создается таблица users_voice с полями user_id, post_id. Вопрос: куда теперь запихнуть нужный мне параметр для каждого голоса (тот самый anonym)? Или мне нужен какой-то другой подход?

Comment: Может быть вам сделать сущность Voice с полями user_id, post_id и anonym. Связи от User и Post к Voice будут один ко многим.

Comment: А анонимные голоса хоть чем-то отличаются друг от друга? Есть какой-то механизм защиты от накруток? Хранит ли этот механизм хоть что-то в БД?

Comment: @АлексейШмелёв рассматривал такой вариант. Надеялся обойтись без лишней сущности.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev механизм есть, но БД он не касается. В anonym просто храним 0 или 1 для каждого голоса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз голоса анонимных пользователей ничем не отличаются друг от друга, то для них фактически не нужна отдельная сущность. Вам, на самом деле, нужна связь только для реальных голосов, а для анонимных достаточно числа (при условии, что учет уникальности этих голосов не затрагивает БД).

Вот так может выглядеть ваша сущность поста:

```
class Post
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="voices")
     */
    private $votedUsers;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $anonVotes = 0;

    // ...

    public function getVotesCount()
    {
        return $this->votedUsers->count() + $this->anonVotes;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно как получить тип голоса (анонимный или нет) для конкретного поста текущего пользователя?

Comment: @PavelSokolov Не похоже, что _сам голос_ имеет хоть какое-то значение за пределами поста. Скорее вам нужно _количество голосов_ (поправьте меня, если ошибаюсь). А для раздельного количества можно запросто использовать отдельные геттеры

Comment: идея в том, чтобы в списке проголосовавших пользователей не показывать анонимных

Comment: Ну так сделайте отдельный геттер для проголосовавших пользователей. Предложенный мной вариант даже лучше вписывается в вашу модель, чем вариант с фильтрацией голосов-сущностей на анонимные и реальные

Comment: вашу идею понял, это подойдет. Спасибо.